# Setting new console window size (in characters) Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, console-application

I'm trying to set the size of the Windows terminal based on characters per row and the number of columns, not pixels. I'm a bit lost, but I figured out a few things so far.

To get the current number of dimensions of the console window in the units I want, I can do:

```cpp
const auto hout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hout, &csbi);
 
// Bind x and y
const auto& [wx, wy] = csbi.dwMaximumWindowSize;
std::cout << " { " << wx << ", " << wy << " } " << std::endl;
```

Which, for me, outputs `{ 120, 56 }`. This means 120 chars/row and 56 visible rows.

My problem seems is that, to change this, I seem to have to convert these units to pixels and completely redraw the window. I know how to do this as well, assuming I knew the size I wanted for the window in terms of pixels:

```cpp
HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
RECT console_rect;
GetWindowRect(console, &console_rect);
MoveWindow(console, console_rect.left, console_rect.top, /* nWidth */, /* nHeight */, TRUE);
```

So, I need 1 of 2 solutions.

1. Is there a way to skip the conversion and change the size of the window in terms of chars/row and number of visible rows? If not,
2. How do I accurately convert from my preferred format to pixels? I'm assuming I have to take font sizes into account, which I'm also not completely sure how to do.

Thanks in advance for anyone who's willing to help! I'm using C++20 and the Windows API.

Comment: You can change the screen buffer size. The window is usually under the users control.

Comment: For `2` you can use [`GetCurrentConsoleFont`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getcurrentconsolefont). That returns the font width/height in logical pixels. I don't know how to interpret that data when using a font that's not mono-spaced. I also don't know how many layers of indirection you'll have to wade through to go from logical to physical device pixels.

Comment: use SetConsoleWindowInfo